# TSLint is being deprecated. How does this affect Angular?

Tags: angular, tslint, typescript-eslint

The company I work at is on the brink of starting a new enterprise Angular application.
While reading up on linting, I read that [TSLint is being deprecated](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534).

Since TSLint is included in Angular by default, I started looking for any plans the Angular team has to deal with the deprecation. I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32462), which wasn't very helpful. It pointed me here, and I couldn't find any post related to the issue.

My questions are:

1. As an Angular developer, should I migrate to Typescript ESLint manually for new and/or existing projects?
2. Does the Angular team have any plans to make the eventual migration easier for existing projects?

Answer (score 4):

Nice first post by me, lasted a whole 20 minutes :)

I found my answers in [this Angular CLI issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13732).

1. While using ESLint solves some minor issues, like Typescript 3.7 support, there are still issues with ESLint. For me personally CI performance is enough of a reason to keep using TSLint for now.
2. Migration is planned for Angular 10. I'm sure they will make it as easier than migrating it manually.

Comment: A forked version of Tslint maintained by Microsoft (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin). Also, the typescript team committed to working with the Eslint team to  (https://eslint.org/blog/2019/01/future-typescript-eslint) improve.So should not be a problem

Comment: That is not a forked version of TSLint; it's the VS Code extension that runs TSLint & surfaces its errors to users. Microsoft has not forked Tslint.